# Emitting values from dynamically changing array

Tags: arrays, typescript, dynamic, rxjs, subject

I need to model a scenario where I have a source array of numbers that randomly gets new pushed values or pops. The array is being used as a source for computations that should be repeated in a loop that starts after the last one completes. Every time the array changes the previous computations should be discarded to start them again with the new values.

This is my code

```
let nums: number[] = []

const nums$ = new Subject()

timer(2000, 5000).pipe(
    concatMap(n => of(n).pipe(delay(Math.random() * 1000)))
).subscribe(val => {
    nums.push(val)
    nums$.next(nums)
})

nums$.pipe(
    switchMap(n => of(n).pipe(delay(1000)))
).subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val)
    nums$.next(nums)
})
```

The first timer should simulate the changes made to the array whereas the second pipe represents the computations as a delay.

My solution is somewhat dirty even because the value passed to the `of` operator inside the `switchMap` isn't recognized as array so I don't know how to take advantage of the `from` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `Subject` to manually emit random numbers and update the array, I think it's simpler to simply use a `timer` to generate the random numbers, then use [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) to accumulate them into an array:

```js
const nums$ = timer(0, 1500).pipe(
  map(() => Math.ceil(Math.random() * 15)),  
  scan((array, num) => num > 10  
    ? array.slice(0, -1)  // remove last element (33%)
    : array.concat(num)   // add new element (67%)
  , [])
);
```

Then, you can base your "calculated value" (*lets just call it `sum$` for a simple example*) on `nums$`:

```js
const sum$ = nums$.pipe(
  switchMap(numbers => doCalculation(numbers))
);

function doCalculation(numbers: number[]) {
  return of(numbers.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num, 0)).pipe(delay(1000));
}
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67247451?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) demo.

---

> the value passed to the of operator inside the switchMap isn't recognized as array

If you specify the type on your Subject, the type will get recognized correctly:

```js
const nums$ = new Subject<number[]>();
```

Comment: Great answer and no need to edit or anything, but thought it also worth pointing out that `switchMap(n => of(n).pipe(delay(1000)))` is equivalent to `debounceTime(1000)`.

Comment: The `nums` array should be emitted only after the sum is completed otherwise if the interval emission is too fast the sum (computations) will never be completed once. The timer I have used is too simulate the user interaction pushing new values into `nums` and has nothing to do with my scenario.